# Creation of users via GNMI using Pygnmi Library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a user in a Juniper device using openconfig gNMI.
The provisioning in the device is done via Declarative Configuration meaning anything that is not declared with replace operation will be deleted, so I can't use update operation to create it.

I manage to do it with a replace operation but this erases every user from the branch and set up only the ones added to the json configuration
I can do a get operation to copy the branch and then add the users i want but doesn't shows the passwords of the users. I can set up some fixed passwords for each but the idea is to add it without touching the other users.

I don't know if there is another lib also i can test to use gNMI in Python or you have some examples since there aren't so many with replace op

```
#Modules
from pygnmi.client import gNMIclient
import json

#Variables
ip = '10.45.42.153'
port = 5050
host = (ip, port)

user = [
    (
        "openconfig-system:system/aaa/authentication/users/user[username=newuser]",
        {"username": "newuser" , "config": {"username": "newuser", "password": "Test1234!", "role": "super"}}

    )                          
]

if __name__ == '__main__':


    #superuser: admin/Password
    with gNMIclient(target=host, username='admin', password='Password', debug=True) as gc:
          result = gc.set(replace=u,encoding="json")
```

This is an example of the aaa branch

```
    "system":{
        "aaa":{
            "authentication":{
                "users":{
                    "user":[
                        {
                            "username":"user2",
                            "config":{
                                "role":"super",
                                "username":"user2",
                                "password":"new1234!"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "username":"admin",
                            "config":{
                                "role":"super",
                                "username":"admin",
                                "password":"Password"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "username":"user3",
                            "config":{
                                "role":"super",
                                "username":"user3",
                                "password":"new1234!"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to create a user in a Juniper device using the gNMI protocol with OpenConfig, you can use the "replace" operation.
Using the "replace" operation will remove any existing users not specified in the JSON configuration. To overcome this, you can follow these steps:

1. Retrieve the existing configuration using the "get" operation.
2. Modify the retrieved configuration by adding the new user(s) you want to create.
3. Use the modified configuration with the "replace" operation to provision the device.

For example using `pygnmi` library in Python:

```py
from pygnmi.client import gNMIclient
import json

ip = '10.45.42.153'
port = 5050
host = (ip, port)

new_user = {
    "username": "newuser",
    "config": {
        "username": "newuser",
        "password": "Test1234!",
        "role": "super"
    }
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with gNMIclient(target=host, username='admin', password='Password', debug=True) as gc:
        # Step 1: Retrieve existing configuration
        response = gc.get(models=['openconfig-system'])
        existing_config = json.loads(response.notification[0].update[0].val.json_val)

        # Step 2: Modify the retrieved configuration
        existing_users = existing_config['system']['aaa']['authentication']['users']['user']
        existing_users.append(new_user)

        # Step 3: Use the modified configuration with "replace" operation
        replace_config = {
            "openconfig-system:system": {
                "aaa": {
                    "authentication": {
                        "users": {
                            "user": existing_users
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        replace_request = gc.set(replace=replace_config, encoding="json")
        print(replace_request)
```

the code retrieves the existing configuration, modify it by appending the new user to the existing users, and then use the modified configuration with the "replace" operation.

The code assumes that the existing configuration returned matches schema you provided